# Android Sqlite Database copyDatabase function Paths

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am using the code below to copy the sqlite db, just wondering what is the correct coding for the paths as the Android Studio recommends not to hard code the paths as shown in the image attached. Most answers here also used hard coded /data/data paths.

```
    companion object {

    private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
    private val DATABASE_NAME = "books.db"

    @JvmStatic
    fun copyDatabase(context: Context) {

        LogUtil.loge("copyDatabase")
        try {
            var dir = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases"
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24){
                dir = context.dataDir.absolutePath + "/databases/"
            }
            if(!File(dir).exists()){
                LogUtil.loge("databases dir not exist")
                File(dir).mkdir()
            }
            val outFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME)
            val myOutput = FileOutputStream(outFileName)
            val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
            var length: Int
            val myInput = context.assets.open("databases/$DATABASE_NAME")
            length = myInput.read(buffer)
            while (length > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length)
                length = myInput.read(buffer)
            }
            myInput.close()
            myOutput.flush()
            myOutput.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            LogUtil.loge("unable to copy database")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially use Context's `getDatabasePath("databasename");` to create a File object, then use the File's getParentFile to get the directory as a file and then as the basis of the OutputStream. All you need to do is hard code the database name (and the databases folder within the assets folder).

[getDatabasePath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String))

e.g. something like :-

```
private fun dbcopy(context: Context) {

    val dbfile = File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path)
    if (!dbfile.parentFile.exists()) {
        dbfile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    }
    try {
        val os = FileOutputStream(dbfile)
        // and so on
    } catch (e: IOException) {

    }

}
```

P.S. there is no need to check the version, the above works for all versions that I'm aware of (albeit converted from Java).

You would need to hard code **databases** when opening the asset as it's not a standard/pre-defined/must use folder.

I tend to do the directory check and create as part of checking if the database exists e.g. :-

```
private fun checkDataBase(context: Context): Boolean {

    val db = File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path) //Get the file name of the database
    if (db.exists()) return true // If it exists then return doing nothing

    val dbdir = db.parentFile
    // If the directory does not exist then make the directory (and higher level directories)
    if (!dbdir.exists()) {
        db.parentFile.mkdirs()
        dbdir.mkdirs()
    }
    return false
}
```

The following is a complete helper (less any methods for accessing the database) that will copy the database from the assets databases folder, if the database doesn't exist :-

```
class MyDBHelper(internal var myContext: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(myContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    internal var buffer_size = 1024 * 4

    init {
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            copyDataBase()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {}

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {}

    private fun checkDataBase(): Boolean {

        val db = File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path) //Get the file name of the database
        Log.d("DBPATH", "DB Path is " + db.path) //TODO remove for Live App
        if (db.exists()) return true // If it exists then return doing nothing

        // Get the parent (directory in which the database file would be)
        val dbdir = db.parentFile
        // If the directory does not exits then make the directory (and higher level directories)
        if (!dbdir.exists()) {
            db.parentFile.mkdirs()
            dbdir.mkdirs()
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun copyDataBase() {
        try {

            val myInput = myContext.assets.open("databases" + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME) // Open the Asset file
            val outfile = File(myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString())
            val myOutput = FileOutputStream(outfile)
            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            val buffer = ByteArray(buffer_size)
            var length = myInput.read(buffer)
            while (length > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length)
                length = myInput.read(buffer)
            }
            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush()
            myOutput.close()
            myInput.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val DATABASE_NAME = "thedatabase.db"
        private val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
    }
}
```

- Note that rather than hard coding the File separator it too is obtained according to the system value.